# Device not working in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, dell, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1501 running Ubuntu 12.10. When I go to software sources > additional drivers, I try to select the right driver, for the wireless card, and select apply changes, it tries to install the driver but then says that the device is not working.  The Device is `Broadcom Corporation: BCM4311 802.11a/b/g`  And the Driver is `Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernal-source (proprietart)`  How can I fix this.
This shows error

[image]

Comment: You should provide more information about your graphic card. `lspci  --grep VGA` should help. Also provide more information on the error given.

Comment: First of all please tell us what device you want to download the driver for? Graphic card, wireless module, fingerprint scanner? And what the driver you try to install through 'Additional Drivers' is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run the terminal command:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your wireless device identified as 14e4:4311? If so, the STA driver is incorrect for your device. Get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working.

If 14e4:4311 is not your device, post it here and we'll help.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home

Comment: My device is `14e4:4312` but your commands worked

Comment: I Just have the second revision of the device.

Comment: Glad it's working!